# What is the expiation for indulging in sexual activities after upanayana?

Tags: brahmacharya

I have a question, if a person who masturbates, more than once after entering Brahmacharya stage, what shall he do ? Will he have to live with the regret or can he do something so that he is back to normal as a Brahmachari?

Comment: Hey, Guilt can't sufficiently purify your chitta. Better you search for methods to purify your chitta. Even if you know it is sin you won't be able to control yourself after knowing, so better to work rather than guilt.

Comment: Start doing Sandhyavandanam regularly Shri Krishna says in BG that Nityakarmas like Yagnas etc are prescribed for purification of Dwijas. So do that regularly and slowly but steadily close that hell gate. Btw everytime you do such act think of it as killing an opportunity for jeevatman to take lucky dwija birth your seed spilled is equivalent to killing someone or some opportunities. Also everytime you do that you have to change Yagnopavitam.

Answer (score 4):

There is this following atonement prescribed in Manu Smriti.

> Manu Smriti 11.118. But a student who has broken his vow shall offer
>   at night on a crossway to Nirriti a one-eyed ass, according to the
>   rule of the Pakayagnas.

Voluntary waste of seminal fluid amounts to breaking of the vow for a Brahmachari student.

EDIT- As shown [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19879/4732) breaking a vow is an upapAtaka or a minor sin.

And upapAtaks can be atoned by applying the following means as well. IMO, these methods are relatively less cumbersome to perform than the one given above ( donating one eyed ass etc).

> Manu Smriti 11.258. Or if, pure (in mind and in body), **he thrice
>   repeats the Samhita of the Veda in a forest**, sanctified by three
>   Paraka (penances), **he is freed from all crimes causing loss of caste
>   (pataka).**
>
> Manu Smriti 11.259. But if (a man) fasts during three days, bathing
>   thrice a day, and muttering (in the water the hymn seen by)
>   Aghamarshana, **he is (likewise) freed from all sins causing loss of
>   caste.**

Among the two, i think the second one is easier. It just involves fasting, bathing three times in a day and also reciting the Aghamarshana Suktam which is found in the Rig Veda.

Comment: have you found the prescribed solution in the scriptures? @Rickross and thank you for what you are doing for me

Comment: @savvvv I have updated my answer. chk it, also no problem at all, its my pleasure. Apart from these methods i have also read that there is no better means of destroying sins than chanting the Gayatri mantra. What is the exact number of chants required , is something i need  to check.